# South Migration Error: NoMigrations

Tags: django, database, heroku, django-south

I'm new to South and I'm trying to perform a migration. It worked fine in local, but when I pushed the code to Heroku and tried to migrate I got this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 57, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 200, in migrate_app
    applied_all = check_migration_histories(applied_all, delete_ghosts, ignore_ghosts)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 81, in check_migration_histories
    m = h.get_migration()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/models.py", line 34, in get_migration
    return self.get_migrations().migration(self.migration)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/models.py", line 31, in get_migrations
    return Migrations(self.app_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 64, in __call__
    self.instances[app_label] = super(MigrationsMetaclass, self).__call__(app_label_to_app_module(app_label), **kwds)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.set_application(application, force_creation, verbose_creation)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 162, in set_application
    raise exceptions.NoMigrations(application)
south.exceptions.NoMigrations: Application '<module 'django_extensions' from '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/__init__.pyc'>' has no migrations.
```

In local I did:

```
python manage.py schemamigration spicemodels --auto
python manage.py migrate spicemodels
```

Then I pushed the migration files to Heroku and accessed the app using:

```
heroku run bash --app <app-name>
```

I then went into the correct directory and ran:

```
python manage.py migrate spicemodels
```

That is when I got the error above.

Comment: What's the version of `django-extensions` in development and production? You might've installed a newer version on production which doesn't support the old-style south migrations.

Comment: Or an older version of south which doesn't look in the `south_migrations` directory first. I would definitely check both versions.